# append() function in python behaving strangely

Tags: python

This is the code:

```
import random
mylist=[]
position=[300,300]
while 1:
    randomint = random.randint(1,3)
    print mylist
    if randomint == 3:
        position[0]+=5
        mylist.append(position)
```

and instead of this:

```
[]
[[305, 300], [310, 300]]
[[305, 300], [310, 300], [315, 300]]
[[305, 300], [310, 300], [315, 300]]
[[305, 300], [310, 300], [315, 300]]
```

...
I get this:

```
[]
[[305, 300]]
[[305, 300]]
[[305, 300]]
[[305, 300]]
[[305, 300]]
[[305, 300]]
[[310, 300], [310, 300]]
[[315, 300], [315, 300], [315, 300]]
[[315, 300], [315, 300], [315, 300]]
[[315, 300], [315, 300], [315, 300]]
[[315, 300], [315, 300], [315, 300]]
[[315, 300], [315, 300], [315, 300]]
[[315, 300], [315, 300], [315, 300]]
[[315, 300], [315, 300], [315, 300]]
[[315, 300], [315, 300], [315, 300]]
[[320, 300], [320, 300], [320, 300], [320, 300]]
...
```

Why? It's strange, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you append `position` to the list, you only add a *reference*, not a copy. When then printing `mylist` you are seeing the same shared list being printed several times.

Create a copy when appending with the slice syntax:

```
mylist.append(position[:])
```

Here `position[:]` creates a slice from start to finish, returning a new list object with a shallow copy.